# Create indexed view that contains text columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, indexed

I require to create an indexed view in SQL Server. Two tables are inner joined in this view.
Both tables also contain text columns. The view index is created on an index column of table1.

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_COL1 ON dbo.View1(TABLE1_PK);
```

Error: The index can not be created as the tables also contain text fields.

As those text fields can not be dropped from the view - is there any known workaround that allows indexing of a view an still include text fields columns?

Comment: `text` is deprecated.  Fix your data model so you are using `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: thx for the hint, this is unfortunatley not possible as it is a third party db that we are linking to.